# How to set end date greater the start date using jquery date time picker

Tags: jquery, date, datetimepicker

Am using jquery date time picker set an event's start and end dates.But how can I prevent to select event end date should greater than event start date. I end date selected first then start date should be less than end date.

I have tried using the following code,but didn't worked for me:

```
    $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
        dayOfWeekStart : 1,
        lang:'en',
        minDate: new Date(),
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ 
          $("#endDate").datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
       }  
    });

    $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
        dayOfWeekStart : 1,
        lang:'en',
        startDate:  new Date(),
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
          $("#startDate").datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', dateText);
       }
    });
```

And my html for the page is like:

```
   <form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
        <div class="form-group "> 
            <input type="text" value="" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Start Date"/>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group "> 
            <input type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" id="endDate" name="endDate" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date"/>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group "> 
            <input type="text" value="" name="eventName" class="form-control" placeholder="Event Name"/>

        </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Event" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Nothing at all here? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+datepicker+end+date+start or 
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+datepicker+limit+dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check data difference of start & end date when end date is selected and can try this..

```
$('#endDate').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart : 1,
    lang:'en',
    startDate:  new Date(),
    onSelect: function(dateText){
        var start_date = new Date($('#startDate').val()),
            end_date = new Date(dateText),
            diff  = new Date(end_date - start_date),
            days  = parseInt(diff/(1000*60*60*24), 10);
        if(days < 1){
            alert('End date should be greater than start date!')
            $(this).val('');
            return false;
        }
        //$("#startDate").datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', dateText);

    }
});
```

You can also apply this date difference scripts for start date selection.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working , I think the issue is in the onSelect I tried using alert dateText but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a `js` function and use that function as below.

- **Step 1**
- `Date.prototype.DaysBetween = function () {
          var intMilDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
          var intMilDif = arguments[0] - this;
          var intDays = Math.floor(intMilDif / intMilDay);
          if (intDays.toLocaleString() == "NaN") {
              return 0;
          }
          else {
              return intDays + 1;
          }
      }`
  -

> Use this function in `OnSelect` event as below.

- **Step 2**
- `$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
      dayOfWeekStart : 1,
      lang:'en',
      minDate: new Date(),
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ 
        var tempstartDate = $('#startDate').val();
        var tempEndDate = $('#endDate').val();
       var dateDiff = tempstartDate.DaysBetween(tempEndDate);   // use this function to find the date diff.
        if(dateDiff > 1 ){
                     alert('Your msg...');
           }
     }

  });`

`$('#endDate').datetimepicker({
        dayOfWeekStart : 1,
        lang:'en',
        startDate:  new Date(),
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
          var tempstartDate = $('#startDate').val();
          var tempEndDate = $('#endDate').val();
         var dateDiff = tempstartDate.DaysBetween(tempEndDate);   // use this function to find the date diff.
          if(dateDiff > 1 ){
                       alert('Your msg...');
             }
       }
    });`

Comment: @Randhir Singh - If above answer is useful, Please click on 'correct' and give 'upvote' so it will helps other to find out correct solution Thanks.

Comment: @Randhir Sing - Yes there was a problem in above code....now I updated the answer ...you can try this, hope it will work for you

Comment: It is not working again I think the issues is in the on select.Simple alert() is also not not working when select date.I have tried the following:
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
   dayOfWeekStart : 1,
   lang:'en',
   minDate: new Date(),
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ alert(dateText);
        $("#endDate").datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
     }  });

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this validation using normal Javascript validation

```
frm = document.forms['form_name'];
var startdate = frm.startDate.value.trim();
var enddate = frm.endDate.value.trim();

var start_date = new Date(start_date);

var end_date = new Date(end_date);

if((startdate != "" && enddate == "") || (startdate == "" && enddate != ""))
    alert('Please select start & end date');
else if(end_date < start_date)
    alert('End date cannot be before start date');
else
    frm.submit();
```

This fixed my issue of validating start date and end date in any Date Time Picker library

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery('#yourIDSelector').datetimepicker({
        format:'d.m.Y H:00',
        dayOfWeekStart: 1,
        minDate: new Date()
 });
```